# Best practices for including non-angular pages in an angular page during conversion

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, flask

I am about to convert a large flask app to angularjs. I would like to be able to have both the old app and new app live side by side.

I have enough control over the flask app that I could create a route for every page that returns the "main content" of the page to be ajaxed into a container between the header and the footer.

Are there any issues with this solution that I am not thinking about? I am fairly confident that most of my current code will still work if it is ajaxed in (I use a lot of event delegation vs direct binding etc).

Has this been done before?

*edit*: to everyone who thinks this is too broad, I disagree. I think it will involve defining a "not found" route that requests content from the flask app, parses it and shoves it into the page. I will post some code once I get it working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting my site to use Angular JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669616/converting-my-site-to-use-angular-js)